# RewriteRule redirects to unexpected page

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to change my url through .htaccess in the following way

```
Original URL: http://www.example.com/latest-news.php?id=2/topic=testing
Rewritten URL:http://www.example.com/2/testing
Rule for .htaccess
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /latest-news.php?id=$1&topic=$2 [L]
```

This is working fine but the other files which are existing in a folder are not opening. The url is opening as www.example.com/testing/foo.php but content of the page is of http://www.example.com/2/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with a similar rule like the one bellow?

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z])$ /latest-news.php?id=$1&topic=$2 [L]
```

Can't really test it on my server but you can adapt it to suit your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]*)$  /latest-news.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L]
```

Since second part consists characters and digits So I modify the answer of stoica. Thanks @stoica

Comment: Don't post a separate answer. Accept answer from @BogdanStoica that helped you.

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad that I could help!